# Concurrent issue in React.JS

Tags: reactjs

I create example function to delete data object and it will be called by others like SignalR event (msg with id  to be deleted).

```
const [data, setData] = useState[];

const remove = (id) => {
  const arr = data.filter((item) => item.id!== id);
  setData(arr);
}
```

I am facing an issue when delete messages were sent at the same time and some data records weren't deleted per expected.  I know that it is the concurrent issue when I didn't lock the data obj. But I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion please!!.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the functional pattern for setState.

```
const remove = (id) => {
  setData(data => data.filter((item) => item.id!== id));
}
```

More reliable when you want your new state to be derived from the previous state value.